# prevent angular material list behavior when click on input field

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here the list is generating

[image]

the output look

[image]

when i click on input field it check/unchecked. how can i prevent this behavior.

Comment: Why are you using mat-selection-list if you want to prevent the default checkbox operation? You can use mat-list and add a custom checkbox input inside the loop. And assign its value dynamically inside click function.

Comment: yes you are right. i did it and now i am seeing you are telling exactly that what i did. thanks.